# How to create a double underscore with no space in between?

Tags: spacing, urls

I want to add a link to my link of citations, and in the link there are several places where there are two consecutive underscores.  Using the usual _ for an underscore, I did this:

```
\_\_
```

Specifically for my link, I have this right now:

```
http://law.onu.edu/sites/default/files/457\_F{\_\_}Supp\_\_957
```

but then I get a space in between the two underscore symbols.

[image: What is happening]

Any ideas?

Comment: `\_\kern-.14ex\_`

Comment: Thank you so much! I found that `\_\kern-.5ex\_` 

put them right next to each other in my doc.  Phew.

Comment: I would recommend leaving it as _ _ with the space . . . If they touch, I need to get a ruler to tell if you mean 1, 2, 3, 4, etc underscores.

Comment: Is there a convention to leave the spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create line two times longer than `\_`, the solution may be as the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newlength\dunder
\settowidth{\dunder}{\_}

A\_B

A\rule{2\dunder}{0.4pt}B

Or as a definition

\newcommand{\twound}{\rule{2\dunder}{0.4pt}} % As named as you want

A\twound{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Different versions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\adbackslash}{\raisebox{-.6ex}{--}}
\newcommand*{\bdbackslash}{\textunderscore\kern-.1355ex\textunderscore}
\newcommand*{\cdbackslash}{\_\kern-.1355ex\_}
\begin{document}
\adbackslash
\bdbackslash
\cdbackslash

When fonts are \verb|\Huge|

\Huge
\adbackslash
\bdbackslash
\cdbackslash

\end{document}
```

[image]